# Mac OS - Swift - Get screen containing the dock

Tags: swift, macos, screen

I would like to get the screen containing the dock and the menubar.
Is there a way to do this?
I've check Apple documentation about `NSScreen` but couldn't find any information about that.

Thanks!

Comment: @Willeke: Nice idea, but probably won't work if dock auto-hiding is enabled.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for the suggestion. I already checked this post but it is more than 10 years old and a bit hacky. I was hoping for a more proper way to do it and as DarkDust suggested, I'm not sure it would work with the auto-hiding and the appbar with notch.

Comment: Is the appbar the menu bar?

Comment: @Willeke yes, the main menu bar wit the clock & stuff

Comment: See [How can I detemine which screen holds the menubar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163343/how-can-i-detemine-which-screen-holds-the-menubar)

Comment: I totally missed this reading the doc. Thank you @Willeke !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the answer was, as @Willeke suggested, in the documentation of `NSScreen.screens` (see:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/1388393-screens).

The screen considered as main (with the menubar) is the one with index 0.
It is not the same as `NSScreen.main` which is the screen with the current active window.